# Raspberry Pi Pre-Installed BlueZ

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-buster, bluez

I am working on the Raspberry Pi 4 board with the Raspbian Buster OS.
I have found that the BlueZ library Pre-Installed on the Raspbian Buster OS.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothd -v
5.50
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 5.50-1.2~deb10u1+rpt2
```

If the library is Pre-Installed,

1. How do I edit configurations?
2. How do I upgrade the BluZ version? (Is there any command-line option?)

Comment: upgrades are done using `apt get update && apt get upgrade` - as for configuration - maybe `man bluetoothd` will show you someting ... or maybe `dpkg-reconfigure bluez`

Comment: 1. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade will not update the BlueZ library to the latest version.
2. Is there any reference guide to configure the BlueZ for enabling the GATT Services using man bluetoothd.

Comment: 1 - if it's installed using apt ... which it is ... then it will upgrade to the latest available in raspberry pi OS, 2 - did you run man bluetoothd? it says the main config file is ` /etc/bluetooth/main.conf` ... which is extremely commented - there's even a section `[GATT]` ...

Comment: wait for debian (raspbian) bullseye for 5.55 - there's 5.54 in buster-backports - which version do you "need"

Comment: @JaromandaX I said it's pre-installed on raspbian os. while running apt-get update && apt-get upgrade the blueZ version updated to the 5.50 only. 
For GATT configurations, I would like to use my device as a GATT server, for that what will be the class mentioned in the main.conf and else configurations too...
What will be the expected launch date for Debian (raspbian) bullseye? Is that a stable version?

Comment: yes, so, it updated to the latest version available for the raspberry pi OS buster - what version do you need?

Comment: I need BlueZ 5.58

Comment: well, that's not even in Bullseye - you'll have to build it yourself - I wonder what version is available using snap - https://snapcraft.io/install/bluez/raspbian

Comment: Is that mean, there is only one way for updating the BlueZ library via the GitHub repository? & I am still confused with the Bluetooth configurations for the GATT server application. Dose BlueZ provide any document for explaining each parameters mentioned in the  ` /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.

Comment: there's *snap* as I mentioned ... but yeah, until debian/raspbian update bluez, you cn only apt install what they offer

Comment: what about a document explaining each parameter that is used to configure the Bluetooth GATT service. For Ex. class, device type, signature, authentication types.

Comment: seriously, this shouldn't be this difficult ... documentation ... there's documentation ... https://github.com/bluez/bluez/tree/master/doc

Comment: @JaromandaX: Thanks for the information.